# Unable to get all necessary headers because cannot set the interface correctly to monitor mode

Tags: wifi, router, scapy, rssi

I want RSSI from 'WiFi probe requests' (when somebody is searching for a WiFi hotspots) but have been unable to get all necessary headers. I am using Scapy on a firmware flashed on a D-Link DIR-505 Open-WRT compatible router.

On more research on stackoverflow I realized the problem is because of not being able to set interface correctly. I need help in setting monitor mode on interface on the router which has limited space.

Thanks

Comment: This is more a question for here : http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks cosmo0, will post it there

Answer (score 0):

The mode dose not depend on the limited space of the router, but on the driver.
I have set up the monitor mode on an OpenWRT router (WNDR3700v4) by using `iw`. And `tcpdump` for packet capture. You may refer to this [link](https://sandilands.info/sgordon/capturing-wifi-in-monitor-mode-with-iw)